# How can I store the Circuit Breaker state into the database?

Tags: c#, api, polly, circuit-breaker

I have to implement the circuit breaker into my application. Everthing goes fine, the circuit breaker is working but I need to store its state into the database. How can I do that? I couldn t find anything reliable on the web.

Here is the code that is working for the circuit break:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddTenantService(this
IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var tenantServiceSettings = configuration?.GetSection("ApiEndpoints");
            var tenantServiceBaseUrl = tenantServiceSettings.GetValue<string>("TenantServiceApiLink");

            var advancedCircuitBreakerPolicy = Policy
                .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(0.5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 2, 
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), onBreak: (exception, context) => Console.WriteLine($"{exception}"), onReset: null);
 
            services.AddHttpClient<ITenantService, TenantService>(client => { client.BaseAddress = new
Uri(tenantServiceBaseUrl); })
                .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                .AddPolicyHandler(advancedCircuitBreakerPolicy);
            return services;
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Polly offers no mechanism for storing the state of circuit-breakers in a database.

---

The Polly team have authored a durable (ie persistent) distributed circuit-breaker, which can be found here: https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.AzureFunctions.CircuitBreaker

This durable, distributed circuit-breaker is hosted in Azure Functions as a Durable Entity function.  (You take the code and host it yourself in your own Azure Functions instance.)

The durable, distributed circuit-breaker can be consumed:

- within an Azure functions app - by plain Azure functions or by durable orchestration functions;
- from anywhere, over an https API.